# How many hitpoints does Reinhardt's shield have to have to block D.Va's ultimate?

Tags: overwatch

D.Va's ultimate Self Destruct does 1,000 points of damage. Reinhardt's shield can absorb up to 2,000 points of damage before breaking, so a fully charged shield can easily block D.Va's ultimate.

**What happens, however, if Reinhardt tries to block D.Va's ultimate with a shield that has less than 1,000 hit points remaining**, such as 200 hit points? Is the remaining 800 damage still completely absorbed by the shield (before it breaks), or does the damage carry over to Reinhardt's health pool?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

All barriers, such as Reinhardt's shield, Winston's barrier projector, and Zarya's personal shields, will completely negate an attack that deals more damage than they can absorb. A Reinhardt shield with 1 health will still block 1000 damage from Self-Destruct.